# adding username and extra info for user while signingup angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to add username when signup and display username when I logged in, I used angularfire2 and angular 4, I can signup with e-mail and password but I can't add extra info like name or image.

This is auth.service.ts:

```
export class AuthService {
   authState: any = null;
   constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
          private db: AngularFireDatabase,
          private router:Router) {

        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
          this.authState = auth
        });
      }

 // Returns true if user is logged in
get authenticated(): boolean {
return this.authState !== null;
 }

// Returns current user data
get currentUser(): any {
return this.authenticated ? this.authState : null;
 }

// Returns current user UID
get currentUserId() {
// console.log(currentUserId);
 return this.authenticated ? this.authState.uid : '';
 }

// Returns current user display name or Guest
get currentUserDisplayName(): string {
  return this.authState['displayName'];
 }

//// Email/Password Auth ////
signupUser(email:string, password:string) {
  return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
     password)
  .then((user) => {
    this.authState = user;
    this.updateUserData()
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
 }
////signin////
signinUser(email:string, password:string) {
 return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then((user) => {
     this.router.navigate(['/calendar']);
     this.authState = user;
     this.updateUserData()
   })
   .catch(error => console.log(error));
 }
//// Sign Out ////
logout(): void {
this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
this.router.navigate(['/login'])
 }
```

Signup form (signup.component.html):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignup(f)" #f="ngForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Enter your name </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control id="name" 
          [(ngModel)]='name' name="name">
                </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Enter you email </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" 
          [(ngModel)]='email' name="email" required>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
           <label for="password"> Enter Password </label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
            [(ngModel)]='password' name="password" required>
            </div>

            <button class="btn rounded-btn" type="submit" 
           [routerLink]="['/login']" [disabled]="!f.valid" 
          (click)="onSignup(f)"> Register </button>&nbsp;
             </form>
```

signup.component.ts:

```
  onSignup(form: NgForm){
  const name = form.value.name;
  const password = form.value.password;
  const email = form.value.email;
  this.authService.signupUser(email, password);
 }
```

How can I pass the name to be added to the user's info in firebase and display the name of the current user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use updateProfile for the username (displayName), for example:

```
user.updateProfile({
    displayName: "Superman"
}).then(function() {
    console.log("updateProfile success");
}, function(error) {
    console.log("updateProfile", error);
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

For other user properties: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Edit. With your code, something like the following:

```
signupUser(email:string, password:string) {
  return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
     password)
  .then((user) => {
    user.updateProfile({displayName: "Superman"});
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
 }
```

Comment: You can't use it within the `then` callback of `signinUser`?

Comment: sorry i don't understand , u mean i write the user.updateProfile within then callback ???

Comment: Sorry, in `signupUser` is the correct place. See edit.

Comment: Thank you for helping , it's okay now :)